# guava and javafx

Tags: guava, google-apps, google-contacts-api

I'm programming a javafx app to retrieve google contacts.

After Cleaning and Building the app with netbeans and execute the app in my web browser (firefox), everything goes well but when the app is located in a diferent server the application throws a "ClassCircularityError" with "com.google.common.collect.Multisets".

This error only happen when the app try to execute  the next code:

```
ContactFeed result = service.getFeed(url, ContactFeed.class);
```

and this is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: com/google/common/collect/Multisets
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultiset.iterator(AbstractMultiset.java:64)
at com.google.common.collect.ConcurrentHashMultiset.iterator(ConcurrentHashMultiset.java:57)
at com.google.gdata.client.SimpleCookieManager.getCookies(SimpleCookieManager.java:72)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getCookies(GoogleService.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest$GoogleCookieHandler.get(GoogleGDataRequest.java:358)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setCookieHeader(HttpURLConnection.java:1180)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:612)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1320)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFields(HttpURLConnection.java:2683)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.isOAuthProxyErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:566)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:557)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1034)
at mypackage.myApp.start(myApp.java:51)
at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$1.run(FXApplet2.java:131)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
```

"com.google.common.collect.Multisets" is inside guava.

I don't know why the app fails when everything is located in a diferent server and not in my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have multiple versions of some Guava classes on the classpath, causing the error during the class loading. Make sure you don't have multiple versions of the guava jar, or both guava.jar and google-collections.jar (the older project), in your classpath. And check that the gdata client jar doesn't embed a copy of guava.